# Set background color of WPF Textbox in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, background-color

How can I change the background and foreground colors of a WPF Textbox programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

```
textBox1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
textBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
```

WPF Foreground and Background is of type `System.Windows.Media.Brush`. You can set another color like this:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
textBox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
textBox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));
textBox1.Background = System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrush;
```

Comment: If we want to set a hex value to the color attribute , how it can be done??

Comment: You could use something like

Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromRgb( r, g, b ) );

Comment: There is also the much prettier `LinearGradientBrush` :)

Comment: Be sure to include System.Windows.Media.

Answer (score 120):

If you want to set the background using a hex color you could do this:

```
var bc = new BrushConverter();

myTextBox.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FFXXXXXX");
```

Or you could set up a SolidColorBrush resource in XAML, and then use findResource in the code-behind:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushFFXXXXXX">#FF8D8A8A</SolidColorBrush>
myTextBox.Background = (Brush)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("BrushFFXXXXXX");
```

Comment: It is much preferable to use `(System.Windows.Media.Brush)Application.Current.FindResource("BrushFFXXXXX");` as your application will not throw a threading exception if it is upgraded to use multiple dispatcher threads in the future.

Comment: Where should `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushFFXXXXXX">#FF8D8A8A</SolidColorBrush>` be declared?  When I try do so inside `<Window x:Class ...` I get error: "The property 'Content' is set more than once"

Answer (score 24):

I take it you are creating the TextBox in XAML?

In that case, you need to give the text box a name. Then in the code-behind you can then set the Background property using a variety of brushes. The simplest of which is the SolidColorBrush:

```
myTextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert hex to RGB:

```
string ccode = "#00FFFF00";
int argb = Int32.Parse(ccode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Color FromArgb is accepting byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b, not int

Answer (score 6):

You can use hex colors:

```
your_contorl.Color = DirectCast(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D8E0A627"), Color)
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been answered in another SOF post. However, you could do this if you know the hexadecimal.

```
textBox1.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#082049");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at `Color.FromRgb`?

Answer (score 0):

BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();

textName.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF7BFF64");

buttonName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

Reference Here
https://www.it-mure.jp.net/ja/c%23/c%EF%BC%83%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7wpf%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E8%89%B2%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/957683208/