# Windows 8 XAMl C# add watermark to textbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How can i add watermark to textbox in WINRT XAML C# code for Windows 8 application. There is a direct property for tooltip but same is not for Watermark so what is the shortest and efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill a control with the watermark you want to display, such as an [Image control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap), place a TextBox over it (such as by putting them both in a grid with the same Row and Column) and set the Background to [`Brushes.Transparent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap).

See [Set background color of WPF Textbox in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979876/set-background-color-of-wpf-textbox-in-c-sharp-code) for more information on Brushes and setting the TextBox pacground.

Answer (score 6):

- Goto **ManageNugetPacageManager** -> search for **Winrt Xaml Toolkit** -> then install the
  **winrt xaml toolkit**
- then goto xaml page where you want to add watermark textbox
- Then define the below namespace to xaml page
  `xmlns:local="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"`
- then goto the position where you want to add  **watermarktextbox** add this following line below `<local:WatermarkTextBox   WatermarkText="MyWaterMarkText" />`

i hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [WatermarkTextBox](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe0226ad68bb#WinRTXamlToolkit%2fControls%2fWatermarkTextBox.cs) from the WinRT XAML Toolkit for out of the box solution. You could also implement one as an attached behavior using a Popup or by injecting a watermark TextBlock (or any other watermark UIElement) into the visual tree of the TextBox (though that is not supported by the Toolkit... yet).