# Chnage Telerik WPF button color via code

Tags: c#, css, .net, wpf, telerik

I learning `WPF` and build an simple application.
This is my button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddFiles" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1046,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="111" Height="34" FontSize="20" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" 
        Background="{x:Null}" MouseEnter="btnAddFiles_MouseEnter" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

And this is how it looks like:

http://s27.postimg.org/h0iq4mrrz/image.png

I have changed the button background color to `Transparent` so the background color the you see is all my application background color.
All i want to do is when the mouse is over the button change the background color to `Transparent`.
Currently this is the current when mouse is over:

http://s30.postimg.org/x61ssujnx/image.png?noCache=1411485462

So i registered to  `MouseEnter event`:

```
private void btnAddFiles_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //btnAddFiles.Background = // change the color
}
```

But i can see that `btnAddFiles.Background` require `Brush` and nor `Color`
Any idea hot to change it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set background color of WPF Textbox in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979876/set-background-color-of-wpf-textbox-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't see your pictures but this is how we change back color in wpf:

```
btnAddFiles.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

and you can use your code in a mouse enter and mouse leave event.

**1st Edit**

```
private void btnAddFiles_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btnAddFiles.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
}

private void btnAddFiles_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btnAddFiles.Background = Brushes.Lime;
}
```

**2nd Edit:**

for changing border color and thickness:

```
button1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
Thickness t = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
button1.BorderThickness = t;
```

also change your margin, it is out form. try for example

```
Margin="50,50,0,0"
```

let me know if you get your answer.

Comment: Something is very strange, when the mouse leave the application all the application color changed to Lime. BTW can i make the border when the mouse over the control transparent too ?

Comment: you should change your button background but it seems you have changed your application background to lime. make a new project and test my code without any other changes in your code it will work fine. and for the border i am editing my answer.

Comment: The problem that all my form changed solved, i put your code inside my button MouseEnter event and after the mouse is over the button i can still see the button border (the button rectangle that marked in some color) - any idea how to make it invisible ?

Comment: in border thickness change all 5 to 0 then you don't have any border.    Thickness t = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: I want all the rectangle to dispensary, with Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0) this is not the case

Comment: i didn't understand what you said. you don't need thickness in this code. according to your question you wanted to know how to use brush and i answered that, now if you have a new question so ask a new question don't put all your questions in this post.