# copy to clipboard from disabled Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox disabled but would like the user to still be able to copy its content to the clipboard. However when IsEnabled is not set copy/paste is not allowed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess a ReadOnly should be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not really supposed to interact with a "disabled" control.

Instead, set the [`TextBox.IsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.isreadonly.aspx) property to true.

If you want it to "look" disabled, you could [set the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979876/119527) to grey, like it is when it is disabled.