# How to lighlight link in text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have to create some controls similar to a control `TextBox`. But I want this control can Highlight link as `RichTextBox`, Because I have problem with `RichTextBox` so i can't use it. How do I highlight a link in a `TextBox`? or I have to set each property by a line of code?

I want to display it in a `TextBox` as shown below:

[image: not use Richtextbox]

Comment: please post your codes here

Comment: Curernt i not yet coding for this issue

Comment: [For WPF:Set background color of WPF Textbox in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/979906/3060520)

Comment: First try something, then post your question here with your codes when you are having an issue.

Comment: In Standard Winforms you cannot do that, TextBox shows simple text. maybe you can third party controls for that.

Comment: You can use WPF Instead

Comment: *"Because I have problem with RichTextBox so i can't use it."* What problem? Why not ask about that instead? The RichTextBox is what you want to use for displaying formatted text. There is no way to display formatted text in a regular TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A simple TextBox control cannot be used to display formatted text.

A hyperlink is just specially formatted text: all it really does is change the foreground color to blue and the text style to underlined. TextBox controls don't allow this type of granularity. *All* text in the control has the same formatting applied to it.

What you would need to use is a RichTextBox control. This is specifically designed for displaying formatted text, and not only does it allow you to define arbitrary formatting for specific bits of text, but it has built-in support for detecting and highlighting hyperlinks. You say in your question that you had a "problem" with using the RichTextBox, so that is really the question that you should have been asking.