# C# Equivalent code for xaml phrases

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need too add some control unit such as `Grid`, `Checkbox` ,`Textblock` and ... dynamically in my C# Code.

Assume XAML node like:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="24" Click="CheckBoxes_Click"/>
```

Its C# equivalent is

```
AddNewCheckBox()
{
     CheckBox NewCheckBox = new CheckBox ();
     NewCheckBox.Content = "CheckBox1";
     NewCheckBox.Height = 24;
     NewCheckBox.Click += CheckBoxes_Click;
}
```

But there are many XAML assignment which it is hard to understand their C# equivalent.
As an example what should I write in my c# to create a `CheckBox` like this?

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Margin="68,41,0,0" Background="Black"
          Height="Auto" Click="CheckBoxes_Click"/>
```

Is there any way to understand how XAML parser maps phrases to C# code?

Comment: [Background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979876/1997232), etc...

Comment: Why in code and not using dynamic xaml with templates? Easier and much cleaner

Comment: Unclear what you mean by `how XAML parser maps phrases to C# code`

Comment: The Margin property is of type Thickness which has a TypeConverter set of type ThicknessConverter, this type knows how to "map phrases". Is this what you refer to in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to understand how XAML parser maps phrases to C# code?

Looking at this example:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
          Margin="68,41,0,0"
          Background="Black"
          Height="Auto"
          Click="CheckBoxes_Click"/>
```

If we want to understand how the XAML parser knows how to set more complicated properties (ones that cannot simply use the `TryParse()` methods of the types) we need to look at the types of the properties.

If you look at the `Margin` property for example it is of type `Thickness` and if you look at that type you will find this attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ThicknessConverter))]
```

If you look at that type (in PresentationFramework.dll) with for example dotPeek you will find `ConvertFrom(...)` and `ConvertTo(...)` methods that take care of the conversion. The internal method `FromString(...)` contains the relevant parts for this example.

Answer (score 0):

To create checkbox like that you should write it like this:

```
AddNewCheckBox()
{
     CheckBox NewCheckBox = new CheckBox ();

     NewCheckBox.Content = "CheckBox1";
     NewCheckBox.Height = 24;
     NewCheckBox.Click += NewCheckBox_Click;
     NewCheckBox.Margin = new Thickness(64, 41, 0, 0);
     NewCheckBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black);
     //or like this: NewCheckBox.Background = Brushes.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what should I write in my c# to create a check box like this?

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" 
          Margin="68,41,0,0" 
          Background="Black" 
          Height="Auto" 
          Click="CheckBoxes_Click"/>
```

The above equates to

```
var checkBox = new CheckBox () {
    Content = "CheckBox",
    Margin = new Thickness(64, 41, 0, 0),
    Background = Brushes.Black,
    Height = Double.NaN              
};
checkBox.Click += CheckBoxes_Click
```

Answer (score 0):

> As an example what should I write in my c# to create a CheckBox like this?

The same more or less. Each attribute in XAML maps to a property in C#. So the equivalent would be:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.Content = "CheckBox";
checkBox.Margin = new Thickness(68,41,0,0);
checkBox.Background = Brushes.Black;
checkBox.Click += CheckBoxes_Click;
```

The type of the `Background` property is `Brush`. And the type of the `Margin` property is `Thickness`. You can confirm this by looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

The XAML processor is able to translate the string "Black" to a `Brush` and the value "68,41,0,0" to a `Thickness` for you. The C# compiler is not. Apart from this, you are setting the exact same properties of the exact same class.